# Xcode & 64 bit & 32 bit Question

Tags: xcode

I have a 32bit iMac that I am writing an iPhone app in Xcode with, and I was wondering if I saved my project to a flash drive and dropped it on my MacBookPro which is 64 bit and continued to code the iPhone project on my laptop in Xcode would this cause a problem? I don't see how it would since the target is not for either of those computers, but I thought I would ask since I would like to work on the project when I am not always around my iMac. Are there any gottcha's with doing this that I should look out for?

Thanks,

I00I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this works fine.  The compilers take source and compile to a particular target architecture; this is specified by the "-arch" flag to GCC.  The executable produced is independent of the architecture that produces it.  A compiler is a machine that takes input and produces output.  It just takes your source and produces the output for the architecture you specify, no matter what the architecture on which the compiler is running.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thanks a bunch for confirming it!